# Drag a loaded object with threejs?

Tags: three.js, draggable

I've been trying to get a loaded object to be draggable in threejs. The first block of code below (which is only a snippet) displays a cube and I can rotate the view, but not the cube itself.

The second block of code creates a box that is draggable, but I want to be able to do more than just drag boxes. Like maybe drag a teapot! Thus the desire to drag a loaded object.

Why can I move the box when I create it with threejs, but not when I load it? How do I fix this?

The code derived from: http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_interactive_draggablecubes.html

```
// var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 40, 40, 40 );

var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
loader.load('static/obj/cube.obj', function(object) {

    // var object = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, 
                    new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: Math.random() * 0xffffff } ) );

    object.position.x = Math.random() * 100 - 50;
    object.position.y = Math.random() * 60 - 30;
    object.position.z = Math.random() * 80 - 40;

    scene.add( object );

    objects.push( object );

});
```

---

```
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 40, 40, 40 );

// var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
// loader.load('static/obj/cube.obj', function(object) {

var object = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, 
             new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: Math.random() * 0xffffff } ) );

object.position.x = Math.random() * 100 - 50;
object.position.y = Math.random() * 60 - 30;
object.position.z = Math.random() * 80 - 40;

scene.add( object );

objects.push( object );

// });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below works and allows me to drag the object because the way I drag objects requires a mesh as a child of the scene.

```
if (objfile) {

        var texture = new THREE.Texture();
        var img = new THREE.ImageLoader();
        img.load('static/material/red.png', function(image) {
            texture.image = image;
            texture.needsUpdate = true;
        });

        var objModel = new THREE.OBJLoader();
        var mesh;

        objModel.load('static/obj/' + objfile + '.obj', function(object) {
            object.traverse(function(child) {
                if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
                    child.material.map = texture;
                    mesh = child;
                }
            });

            scene.add(mesh);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

loading an obj replaces making the new THREE.boxGeometry() part not new THREE.Mesh(). this code doesn't seem to be without errors.

Anyway, take a look at the code below, notice that inside loader.load I changed the second argument from **object** to **geometry** and uncommented the mesh making:

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
loader.load('static/obj/cube.obj', function(geometry) {

    var object = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, 
                    new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: Math.random() * 0xffffff } ) );

    object.position.x = Math.random() * 100 - 50;
    object.position.y = Math.random() * 60 - 30;
    object.position.z = Math.random() * 80 - 40;

    scene.add( object );

    objects.push( object );

});
```

now OBJLoader gets the geometry, and uses it to make a mesh. It makes more sense doesn't it?

Comment: Thank you for answering! Although when I do what you suggested, my object doesn't load.

Comment: It says there are errors in three.min.js, but I never messed with that. "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' or 'center' of undefined."

Comment: I think it is referencing your obj file not this code